# Reverse a linked list using recursion in cpp

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I'm getting empty list as output, Can anyone help me out with this.

```
ListNode* reve(ListNode* L,ListNode* t){
        if(L->next==NULL){
            t=L;
            print(t);
            return L;
        }
        ListNode* k = reve(L->next,t);
        k->next=L;
        L->next=NULL;
        return L;
    }
    ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* temp=NULL;
        reve(head,temp);
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code is supposed to work? Explain what each line does and how it fits into the bigger picture?

Comment: To me (trying to debug in my head since I don't have enough code to debug) the code will only print the tail node of the original list.

Comment: it is unclear what the input and the outputs of both functions are intended to be.

Comment: I believe `reverseList(ListNode* head)` will return NULL always since temp is passed by value to reve()

Comment: One other concern. Is this code supposed to create a new reversed list preserving the order of the original list or can you destroy the original list?

Comment: It's a good idea to give your variables more descriptive names than `L`, `t` and `k`.  Something like `first` and `rest` as parameters would help you know what to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

The logic makes sense, it's just that the printing of the list should come after the list has been reversed. You should remove `print(t)` and instead put `print(temp)` after the call to `reve()` in the bottom function.

`t` should also be a pointer to a pointer in order to change the value of the passed-in pointer:

```
ListNode* reve(ListNode* L, ListNode** t) {
  if (L->next == NULL) {
    *t = L;
    return L;
  }
  ListNode* k = reve(L->next, t);
  k->next = L;
  L->next = NULL;
  return L;
}

ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
  if (!head) return NULL;
  ListNode* temp;
  reve(head, &temp);
  print(temp);
  return temp;
}
```